# The following prime generator code shows an error when i want prime numbers greater than 1000000.Why?

Tags: c++, primes

The following prime generator code shows an error when i want prime numbers greater than 1000000.Why??
at first it seemed to occur b'cuz of int so i changed it to long but the error is still there....
technically speaking it nit an error the program after running displays the message "primegen.exe has stopped working"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long int a,c,k,d;
k=0;
cin>>a;
cin>>d;
long int b[a];
b[a-1]=0;
for(long int i=2;i<=a;i++)
{
    for(long int j=2;j<=(i/2);j++)
    {
        c=1;
        if ( i%j!=0 )
        {
            continue;
        }    
        else 
        {
            c=0;
            break;
        }   
    }
    if (c!=0)
        {
             b[k]=i;
             //++k;
        }
    else b[k]=0;
    ++k;
 }
 for(long int i=d;i<a;i++)
 {
     if (b[i]!=0)
     {
          cout<<b[i]<<"\t";
     }         
 }   
 cin.ignore();
 cin.get();
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In to which variable are you inputting `1000000`? If it's `a`, then you probably have stack overflow.

Comment: yes i am storing it in a... so why is this not allowed in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a static array won't help in this case. Because you're not allowed to declare such a long static array in C++;
You might want to try

```
int *b = new int [a];
```

declaring the array size dynamically (i.e the array size will be decided at run time). The code should work until variable 'a' exceeds the range of int (–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647).

Comment: Sorry, but suggesting anything but std::vector for a dynamic array is not really helpful.

Comment: Hey, you should try [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find prime nos if you want to find a list of primes nos (like in your case you do). Also, the approach Will Ness has suggested comes from the fact that for a composite no. factors exist in pairs --numbers less than & greater than the square root of given no. --or if square root of the no. is an integer then both will be equal to the square root.
So to find prime numbers, you need to check only upto the square root of that no.

Comment: As per your advice i tried sieve of erastothenes. The code is now faster and compiles wiithout error but still its execution time is more than 5 seocnds for numbers greater than 100000000.

Comment: Also 1 more advice.. Use bool array if you're using any other coz it'll be more space efficient.

Answer (score 1):

[**There is no error in this code**](http://ideone.com/uGChuR).

The code is too slow though, it is almost quadratic. [The projected time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) to reach 1 mln on ideone: 290 seconds.

After fixing it, by changing the inner `for` loop condition from `for(...;j<=(i/2);...)` to `for(...;j<=(i/j);...)`, it runs at ~ n^1.45, empirically, and reaches 1 mln in 1.27 seconds, on Ideone.

Comment: Seems  this is the answer (and 1M *int* in the stack are not a problem on my sys)

Comment: can you suggest me a better way may be log(n) algorithm for this problem